# Dragging points dynamically content in canvas

Tags: javascript

I have an application where I need to move the points I created to a certain part of the canvas. How can I do it?

```
    $("#canvas").click(function(e){
         getPosition(e); 
    });

    var pointSize = 1;

    function getPosition(event){
         var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
         var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
         var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
            console.log(x,y)
         drawCoordinates(x,y);
    }

    function drawCoordinates(x,y){  
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");


        ctx.fillStyle = "#ff2626"; // Red color

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bfe8160h/

[image]

Comment: So if you click on an empty space, it should create a new point, and if you click on an existing point you should be able to drag it?

Comment: @ManuelOtto yes! exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to drag drawn things on canvas, so you're gonna have to store all points' positions, and redraw the whole canvas.
Something like this:

```
var points = []
var drag_point = -1

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){
    var pos = getPosition(e)
    drag_point = getPointAt(pos.x,pos.y)
    if(drag_point==-1){ // no point at this position, add new point
        drawCoordinates(pos.x,pos.y)
        points.push(pos)
    }

});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){
    if(drag_point!=-1){ // if currently dragging a point...
        var pos = getPosition(e)
        //...update points position...
        points[drag_point].x = pos.x
        points[drag_point].y = pos.y
        redraw() // ... and redraw canvas
    }
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){
    drag_point = -1
});

function getPointAt(x,y){
    for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
        if(Math.abs(points[i].x-x)<pointSize && Math.abs(points[i].y-y)<pointSize) // check if x,y is inside points bounding box. replace with pythagoras theorem if you like.
            return i
    }
    return -1 // no point at x,y
}

function redraw(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear canvas

    for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){ // draw all points again
        drawCoordinates(points[i].x,points[i].y)
    }
}

function getPosition(event){
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    return {x:x,y:y}
}

function drawCoordinates(x,y){  
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff2626"; // Red color

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: great! This works fine, one additional question please. How can I get the coordinates of all the points on the canvas? Thanks genius!
http://jsfiddle.net/6uguqnxw/

Comment: all points are stored in the 'points' array. Each point is a object like this {x:0,y:0}

Comment: you are the best! thanks! You won the best answer I want to know if it is easy to join a line from point 1 to point 6 (assuming you have 10 points)

Comment: You're welcome! Drawing a line can be done by iterating over each point and then calling ctx.lineTo(x,y) instead of ctx.arc(). Just google it, its really straight forward ;)

Answer (score 0):

import 
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`
and use jquery to drag your div..Example:

```
$('#divname').draggable();
```